# Powershell: Unable to search imported hashtable

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell, and this behavior has me stumped.

Let's say I've created a hashtable with the following information:

```
$hash= @{
California = 'Sacramento';
Washington = 'Olympia';
Oregon = 'Salem';
Alaska = 'Juneau';
}
$hash
```

Now I want to search for a particular key using a where -match statement:

```
$result = @($layers.getEnumerator() | ? {$_.key -match 'Cal'})
$result
```

This returns with California for the key and Sacramento for the value. All is working as it should.

Now, instead of typing in the keys and values for the table, let's say I want to import them into the hashtable using a CSV file:

```
California,Sacramento
Washington,Olympia
Oregon,Salem
Alaska,Junea
```

Here is my code I created to import the CSV, which works fine:

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\hgordon\Desktop\Maps_to_search\junk.csv -Header "Key","Value"
$layers = @{}
Foreach ($key in $keys) {
    $layers[$key] = $csv 
}
```

My problem is that when I run my search statement above, it returns nothing.

Why won't the search work on the imported hashtable? Is there something that I need to modify with the import statement? What is the difference between an imported hashtable vs one that is manually typed?

Thanks!

Edit: I've edited my import script as follows to make it clearer:

```
$t = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\hgordon\Desktop\Maps_to_search\junk.csv -Header "Key","Value"
$HashTable = @{}
foreach($r in $t)
{
    #Write-Host $r.column1 $r.column2
    $HashTable[$r.Key] = $r.Value
}
$HashTable
```

I still get no result from my search script, though.

Comment: what are `$keys` and `$csv`?

Comment: `Import-Csv` returns a `PSCustomObject` type which is *not* a hashtable.

Comment: The code that you used to create layers from the file does nothing. It's enough to use the output of `Import-Csv`.

Comment: Doesn't   __ $t | ?{$_.Key -like '*Cal*'}__    work?

Comment: @EBGreen \` is the code delimiter.

Comment: Yeah, I edited this thing 47 times ` didn't do it among the 45 other things I tried. Finally gave up. My Markup-Fu is weak...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the job done, you need just to get the output of `Import-Csv` and use it this way:

```
$layers = Import-Csv "C:\yourfile.csv" -Header "Key","Value"
$result = @($layers | ? {$_.Key -match 'Cal'})
$result
```

You don't need to create a `HashTable`.

Comment: If for any reason you want to convert the result to a `HashTable`, you can use `$hash = @{}; $layers | % {$hash[$_.Key]=$_.Value}` Then to search in hashtable, you need to use `$hash.getEnumerator()...`

Answer (score 1):

So in your current iteration, `Import-Csv` is importing the CSV as a `PSCustomObject` type.  Your `Key`/`Value` headers are being used to create a property on the object with an array under each of the CSV, so you end up with:

```
key        value
---        -----
California Sacramento
Washington Olympia
Oregon     Salem
Alaska     Junea
```

---

```
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
key         NoteProperty string key=California
value       NoteProperty string value=Sacramento
```

To build your own hashtable from this information, you'd need to merge it yourself:

```
$HT = @{}
$Csv = Import-Csv ... -Header 'Keys','Values'

For ($i = 0; $i -lt $Csv.Keys.Count; $i++)
{
    ## Here we're using array-accessors
    $HT[$Csv.Keys[$i]] = $Csv.Values[$i]
    #alternative
    #$HT.($Csv.Keys[$i]) = $Csv.Values[$i]
}
```